# Bypass Internet Explorer certificate warning

Tags: powershell

My Question is pretty straight forward.

Can I somehow bypass this warning in PowerShell?

[image]

Right now I'm loading the website with the `InternetExplorer.Application` ComObject, but I could switch to `Invoke-Webrequest` etc. if that's needed

EDIT: Additional information

This is just for a function I wrote to open ILO of our HP Servers via PowerShell. that's the function:

```
function Open-ILO {

    param(  
        [Parameter( 
            Position = 0,
            Mandatory = $true    
        )]
        [string]$computer,
        [switch]$show
    )

    $hash = @{
        "Server1"     = "http://10.0.0.49/"
        "Server2"     = "http://10.0.0.50/"
        "Server3"     = "http://10.0.0.56/"
    }
    $Wert = $hash.get_item($computer)
    if (!$show.IsPresent) 
    { 
        $ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application
        $ie.Visible = $true
        $ie.Navigate($Wert) 
    }
    else { Write-Host $Wert }
}
```

Comment: The error message is most likely due to you using the IP address rather than the registered name of the web site (the name that matches the SSL certificate).   So, just use the *real* URL instead of the IP address

Comment: @egray there is no ssl-certificate. that's why i want to bypass this warning. This is actually just the ILO of one of our HP Servers

Comment: OK, so why are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @egray that's an automatic redirection. ILO forces HTTPS (at least I could not find a google entry yet that told me otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't PowerShell it's Internet Explorer.

The ILO comes with a self-signed certificate which IE does not trust and so shows you the error. Self-signed certificates are not trusted as they are self-generated and require no verification from a certificate authority.

You can either [generate a new cert for the ILO](https://www.vcloudnine.de/replace-hp-ilo-security-certificates/) from an internal certificate authority to replace the self signed cert. If you are using Active Directory you will have a CA.

Or you can [install the self-signed certificate](http://howtonetworking.com/Internet/iis8.htm) so that IE trusts it.

Depending on your workplace security policy there might be security concerns with the second option, as your computer will trust content that is signed with that certificate. Most businesses will be ok with this but some with high security might not.

Comment: hmm ok. seems like io have to do this. I was more interested in just a powershell way to bypass this, also for further problems, but I guess I can't. so i'll do this

Comment: You can do it from Powershell if you want... [Link Article](https://www.kiloroot.com/powershell-script-to-open-a-web-page-and-bypass-ssl-certificate-errors-2/)